# Pushing a segue from xib file not in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am attempting to accomplish something and i was looking for a few tips. I started working on a project that consisted of one xib file. Later on i upgraded to xcode 5 and pretty soon for the rest of my interface files i began using my storyboard however i kept my old xib (mainly cause of how i pass in methods to it) and simply called it like :

```
mapViewController *mapView=[[mapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"mapViewController" bundle:nil location:0 option:@"poe"];
```

Recently I have added new functionality and upon clicking a callout I would like to prepare a segue for a new view to be displayed. 
Firstly in the xib interface. I was wondering if I could from my mapView (not in storyboard) prepare and call a view/segue(in story board) . 
Or if I can simply drop or copy and paste my mapView into my storyboard and then draw my segue connectors to my new view. As I dont think it is necessarily for my to add the mapView to my "story line" however I still want to call is using the method posted above.
However if none of these are feasible please suggest another method. 
Thanks
**UPDATE**
I have moved my xib to my storyboard interface however i am facing a little problem

When i called my map from the xib it would zoom in to a specific location supplied in the `init` method. I am passing in the same parameter but i am having a little trouble recreating my old results in my storyboard

```
    if ( ([receivedRainObject isEqualToString:@"Natural"])) {

 //    mapViewController *mapView=[[mapViewController       //alloc]initWithNibName:@"mapViewController" bundle:nil location:0 option:@"na"];

 //   self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:NO];
 //      [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
  //      [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapView animated:NO];
             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"countryMap" sender:self];   
    }
```

**Then in preparing the srgue**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"countryMap"]) {
         mapViewController *transferViewController=segue.destinationViewController;
        transferViewController.location=0;
        transferViewController.option=@"na";

    }
}
```

**Then in view did load of the map**
location does evaulate to 0 and the breakpoint shows me that all this code is being stepped thru but the region of the coordinates i supplied isnt what is being shown.( the the span or region) 
(however when i call my old xib it works fine)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    if (location==0)
    {

         CLLocationCoordinate2D location1;
         location1.latitude=(double)15.435786;
         location1.longitude=(double)-61.318447;


                    MKCoordinateRegion region;
                    MKCoordinateSpan span;
                    span.latitudeDelta=0.50;
                    span.longitudeDelta=0.40;
                    region.span=span;
                    region.center= location1;

                    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
                    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
               }
}
```

**INIT of my mapview**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil location:(int)num option:(NSString *)row
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.location=num;
        self.option=row;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your mapView, you should be able to do something like this in the callout method:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoardName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
YourViewControllerFromStoryBoard *viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerIdentifierInYourStoryBoard"];
```

Then in your mapView you can override prepareForSegue to do any prep work and then present your viewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a segue between a xib defined controller and a storyboard defined one (or between controllers in two different storyboards either). You can instantiate the controller in the storyboard using the UIStoryboard method, instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, and then push or present it in code. It's not clear from your question why you don't want to move the xib based controller into your "story line". You can create a new controller there, and copy and paste the view from your xib file if you want to go that route.

Comment: I got about to moving it and such but getting a few little issues. edited main question

Comment: @user3737880, what is transferViewController? Is that the controller you're segueing to? Also, if you have code that you need to run in an init method, you need to implement initWithCoder: for controllers that are made in the storyboard rather than initWithNibName:bundle:.

Comment: Yes that is transfewViewController. I used it to hold or "prepare" the variables i want to pass in. Please advise if that isnt done correctly. Also I have shown my initWithNibName but I dont understand why I need to say initWithCoder. shouldnt       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"countryMap" sender:self]; already call the variables that i pass in via the old initWithNibName? and apprantly it is doing so but why does the code execute and not the map not show my desired location

Comment: @user3737880, you don't need to use initWithCoder: if all you need to do is pass data in prepareForSegue. I just wanted to make sure you didn't have other setup your were doing in an init method that wasn't getting run. I don't know why you're not showing the desired region. How are you trying to do that? Still with the code in viewDidLoad you have in your question? I don't see you using the passed in values of location and option (if that's still what you're passing). You should update your question with the code you're using now.

Comment: The location shown is the code in viewdidload. it works when I load my map from the xib and not the storyboard. I dont understnad why since the code runs when called from a storyboard.(should i start a new question for this?)

Comment: @user3737880, yes it would probably better to start a new question.